# Facebook Authentication in Webview

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I am building a native android app that require facebook login each time it's initiated. This authentication is done using the FB SDK (SSO).

Later on in the app, the user opens a WebView to the mobile versions of facebook profile page (http://m.facebook.com/some page). **My problem is that when opening the webview, the user is required to enter user name and password for the facebook site**. Since I already have a facebook access token, and the user might have installed the facebook app, **I assume there some way to skip this annoying phase of signing in** to facebook website in the webview.

I have searched the web and tried different solution with no success. It will help me a lot if someone could posts a solution code that works. Thank you!

Comment: "tried different solution with no success"
Which ones?

Comment: Mainly I tried to work with CookieSyncManager [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) 
But since I am newbie to android that didn't work very well.

Comment: If you use the facebook sdk and you have added your keychain for your app on facebook, you should get the facebook app to display instead of the webview, but maybe that's not what you want? If you use the facebook app you don't need to input a name and password if you're already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

There's tutorial available on Developer site of Facebook for Single-Sign-On (SSO) login. One is [`using webview`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#login) and another is [`using SDK`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso).
Although I think if the user selected remember the password checkbox, it should not ask for login again.

Comment: The facebook mobile web tutorial shows how to create an html page login. Doing so in my app, requires me to bulid an html page that will be integrated with the page I am trying to view… or am I missing something? 
The main thing is, that if the user was trying to see the specific link my app is referencing (~http://m.facebook.com/some page) in the normal chrome browser and the user had the facebook app installed on the device, there was no login required. I want to get the same results for my in app webview.

Comment: I don't know if the facebook app login can be used in the web-view, it can be used in the facebook SDK. The user needs to sign-in once in the web-view and need to select the checkbox to remember the password. The web-view should not ask for password again.