# How to use Facebook access token in android app webview

Tags: android, facebook, android-webview

In my application, the user opens a `WebView` to the mobile versions of facebook profile page (http://m.facebook.com/some_page). My problem is that when opening the `WebView`, the user is required to enter username and password for Facebook. Since I already have a Facebook access token through FB SDK, and the user might have installed the Facebook application, I assume there is some way to skip this annoying phase of signing into Facebook when opening the `WebView`.

In other words, how do I use the access token that I already have in my application's `WebView`?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101030/facebook-authentication-in-webview?rq=1

Comment: thx ZuzooVn, but the link is not have the answer what I wanted. I want to konw that if the way(use the access token that already have in application's WebView) can work or not

Comment: have you tried the tut at fb developer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: I have asked the same question long time ago.. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700409/android-avoiding-two-logins-to-facebook-sdk-and-browser-while-integrating-a-p no answer, I guess it cannot be done.

Comment: Idan, joy or Sunny, did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you can't. The access token you get for your app can only be used in conjunction with the API credentials of your App. I.e. the access token only works in calls that also contain your app's key and secret. Even if you could find a way to pass these into a WebView (which is most probably not covered by [FB's Data Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/#data)), you'd probably have to make the WebView pretend to use the Android SDK (because FB would check the call's source). That's why I suggest you can't.

You also cannot have the WebView use the user's cookies he might have in his stock browser, as each WebView has it's own context for security reasons.

If you're frequently using a WebView for FB in your app, you might be able to pull the auth cookie out of the first WebView, and then insert it into subsequent instances using [CookieSyncManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html). Or you could save the instance state of the first WebView and then reuse it. These are just ideas that might or might not work; I haven't checked them out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, use the cookiemanager is work, as you said, every time webview laod url I must add the cookie that obtain at the same time of getting access token. for example         
wb = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.share_wb);
String url = "http://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.douban.com";
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setCookie(url, Facebook.cookieString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        
wb.loadUrl(url);

Answer (score 1):

You can store that AccessToken separately in Properties and check if you use webview then pass that accessToken and when user use Ti.Facebook then use another AccessToken.

Answer (score -2):

Read this project carefully and try...I tried this example in my project ..It works..

Bu before you taking this example, You have to create a page in facebook and get an application-id, to use in this project

https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidFacebookSample

Comment: This appears to just be a generic Facebook integration (and one using the old API at that) - this doesn't use WebViews anywhere.